# Help identify a feat allowing to spend Rage rounds in exchange for damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, barbarian, content-identification

I've seen this feat before, but I can't find it anymore... All I remember are the following qualities:

- I believe it was a feat, though since my memory has failed me in other areas, it might also be a Rage power
- It allowed you to spend 3 rounds of your Rage in order to gain a benefit
- I believe the benefit was extra damage on a single attack

I originally found it on the [German Pathfinder PRD](http://prd.5footstep.de/), which shouldn't be all that different from the [english counterpart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/). Either way, the German version doesn't include a large variety of books, so I don't imagine it comes from a very exotic edition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You're looking for [Raging Brutality](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/raging-brutality).**

Raging Brutality, from the [Ultimate Combat](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601253591) book, lets you, while raging and power attacking, trade 3 rounds of rage to gain a damage bonus equal to your Con modifier for the rest of your turn (1.5x Con for 2-handed melee weapons).